# SublimeText2: Packages does not show up on Package Control: Install

Tags: sublime-text-2, package-management

When I was installing some packages, I found that my `Package Control: Install Packages` although comes up after pressing enter nothing happens.

Does anyone else had this issue? I do not know after which package it happen. I cam access the menu using `Crtl + Shift + P` but it does not get loaded when search `Package control: Install` and hit enter...nothing happens.

See the following images for illustration.

**Image1**

[image]

and 
**Image2**

[image]

Comment: After you press enter, check the status bar. It'll say `Loading Repositories`. See if there is any error/information there.

Comment: I think I mess around with the user settings and did not know how to get back...I disabled `PC` and reinstalled it. It works but I have yet not got the answer as to why that happened.

Comment: It's hard to tell without any debug info.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

> Package settings > Package control: user > Delete the repository entries that are located at this location
>
> Then Ctrl + Shift + P

Comment: Also make sure there's no old package with the same name on your system -- Preferences -> Browse Packages..